# NullPointerException while deploying Quartz Scheduler with spring on Tomcat

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use Quartz 2.2.0 with spring 3.2.x, using ServletContextListener for listening FileChangeListener class.Is My importManagerService object is null? Any suggestions? Not getting how to resolve it

**Error While deploying**

```
 INFO  [2013-10-04 15:13:16.009] [localhost-startStop-1]: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    ERROR [2013-10-04 15:13:16.061] [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1]: org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job g1.t1 threw an unhandled Exception: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException at
   com.demo.portal.web.importExportFile.ScheduleImportFile.execute(ScheduleImportFile.java:40)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:207)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:560)
    ERROR [2013-10-04 15:13:16.065] [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1]: org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - Job (g1.t1 threw an exception.
    org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:218)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:560)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.happiestminds.portal.web.importExportFile.ScheduleImportFile.execute(ScheduleImportFile.java:40)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:207)
        ... 1 more
```

**FileChangeListener**

```
 public class FileChangeListener implements ServletContextListener {

        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileChangeListener.class);
        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {    
            System.out.println("Stopping Application successfully");
        }

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {  
            logger.info("Initializing Application successfully..........");    
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ScheduleImportFile.class).withIdentity("t1", "g1").build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "g1").startNow()
                    .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(60).repeatForever()).forJob("t1", "g1").build();
            SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler sch;
            try {
                sch = schFactory.getScheduler();
                sch.start();
                sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**ScheduleImportFile**

```
   **public class ScheduleImportFile implements Job{
@Autowired
    ImportManagerService importManagerService;      
@Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
            //some logic for reading and parsing files
            Line no. 40
            Map<String, List<File>> fileToBeProcessMap = importManagerService.getFilesInfo(config);
            Config is object of Configuration class 
    }**
```

**Web.xml**

```
<listener>
         <listener-class>com.demo.portal.web.importExportFile.FileChangeListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: I resolved this issue by removing Autowired annotation but is there any way apart from creating an bean xml, so that we can use autowired object and quartz both. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you identified, We can not auto wire of Spring beans inside Quartz job as Spring Bean's life cycle is forbidden in side a job class.

But we can get those spring beans through a simple way without loading Spring bean xml again.
Here is it.

```
public class MyJob  Implements Job
{
private MyBean myBean;

   @Override
   public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
   {
     getBeansFromContext(context);
     mybean.doSomeThing();
   }

   private void getBeansFromContext(JobExecutionContext context) throws SchedulerException
   {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext)context.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");
        this.mybean=applicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class);
   }
}
```

You should have your schedulerFactoryBean configired in your beans.xml.

```
<beans:bean id="schedulerFactoryBean"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="jobFactory">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory"></beans:bean>
</beans:property>
...
<beans:property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey"
    value="applicationContext" /> -- Here is the guy!!
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @devThoughts. just checked your answer today, was not active  here since long time.. :) upvoted your answer